# VideoJS issue - dynamic video element through Javascript Issue in Firefox

Tags: javascript, asp.net, postback

I have created dynamic video element through Javascript with asp.net.

In firefox, it triggers the post back event. While it works well in IE and Chrome.

So, firefox is the issue here. In firefox, videojs uses webm while in IE and chrome it takes .mp4.